# Key Shortcut for tag suggestion in PAF Schema

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How can we get the suggestions for Tags and its attributes in eclipse ?
`Shift + Space` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To get suggestions for Tags and its attributes in eclipse Use shortcut key
**Ctrl + Space**